# Programmatically change keyboard-layout

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

I'd like to be a really annoying co-worker and write a little program that randomly changes keys on the keyboard, so maybe once an hour the vowels rearrange themselves for a minute or two. I would run the program as a service I suppose..

I know I can do this permanantly via the registry what about during windows running.

Is it possible in XP? Vista? Windows 7?

I'll post the code if we get it worked out. :)

Comment: I have an even better idea. Create a group policy that sets the computers to use Dvorak, and have that setting locked-down. :-P